# Apache redirect 301 /Path/aName/aName.html to /Path/aName.html not working

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache

I think my web host, 1and1, is using Apache 2.4.

As per title, I have a site where I have shortened the URLs to certain pages which have ended up being the sole pages in a given sub-directory, by moving them all into the parent directory, and others which I have grouped into differently named sub-directories. `Redirect 301`s for the former don't work, those for the latter do. My `.htaccess` is quite complex, so I've tried simplifying it to near the minimum required to make `Redirect 301` work at all, but the problem remains, so now I'm beginning to think in terms of 'bug'.

To give more precise examples:

```
redirect 301 /JavaJive/PCHardware/HardwareFaults/HardwareFaults.html /JavaJive/PCHardware/HardwareFaults.html
```

... and all similar patterns, where the lowest source directory name, the source file name, and the destination file name are all the SAME, fail, in this case to redirect to ...

```
/JavaJive/PCHardware/HardwareFaults.html
```

... but a redirect not matching the above pattern seemingly always works, so, for example ...

```
redirect 301 /Shinness/ShinnessBroadband20161130.html /Shinness/FTTCPlans.html
```

... correctly redirects to `/Shinness/FTTCPlans.html`.

Can anyone suggest how to make the failing patterns work, and is this a bug?

**Edit:** As requested, here is the simplified `.htaccess` that still shows the problem ...

```
    ErrorDocument 404 /Help.html#Error404
    Options -Indexes +Includes

    # Enable compresssion
    # Turn this off locally, but on for live site
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE .shtml
    </IfModule> 

    # Enable includes 
    # (for some reason must come after compression section)
    # Not needed locally, but needed for live site
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
    XBitHack on

    SetEnv GKEY <edited>
    SetEnv UKOSKEY <edited>
    RewriteEngine   on
    RewriteBase /

    #   A load of stuff here which has been shown by temporarily
    #   removing it to have no effect on the problem

    #   Redirect expired pages to nearest new equivalents
    redirect 301 /CEMH.html /MacFH.html
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/SatelliteTV/SatelliteCalculator.html /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/SatelliteTV/SatelliteCalculator.shtml
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/SatelliteTV/SatelliteCalculator.php /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/SatelliteTV/SatelliteCalculator.shtml
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/TerrestrialTV/TerrestrialCalculator.html /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/TerrestrialTV/TerrestrialCalculator.shtml
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/TerrestrialTV/TerrestrialCalculator.php /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/TerrestrialTV/TerrestrialCalculator.shtml
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/ChooseTV/ChooseTV.html /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/ChooseTV.html
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/SCART/SCART.html /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/SCART.html
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/TVInTheUK/TVInTheUK.html /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/TVInTheUK.html
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/TVInTheUK/TVInTheUK.rtf /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/TVInTheUK.rtf
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/PCHardware/FloppyDisks/FloppyDisks.html /JavaJive/PCHardware/FloppyDisks.html
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/PCHardware/FloppyDisks/FloppySideTaped.gif /JavaJive/PCHardware/FloppySideTaped.gif
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/PCHardware/FloppyDisks/FloppyTaped.gif /JavaJive/PCHardware/FloppyTaped.gif
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/PCHardware/HardwareFaults/HardwareFaults.html /JavaJive/PCHardware/HardwareFaults.html
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/PCHardware/PCBootProcess/PCBootProcess.html /JavaJive/PCHardware/PCBootProcess.html
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/PCHardware/SCSI/SCSI.html /JavaJive/PCHardware/SCSI.html
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/PCHardware/SoundBlasterLive/SBLiveConnectivity.html /JavaJive/PCHardware/SBLiveConnectivity.html
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/GoogleGoogle.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/GoogleGoogle.shtml
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/GoogleGoogle2.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/GoogleGoogle.shtml
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/GoogleOpenLayers.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/GoogleOpenLayers.shtml
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/OSLPTileMap.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/OSLPTileMap.shtml
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/OST50TileMap.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/OST50TileMap.shtml
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/SRTMTileMap.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/SRTMTileMap.shtml
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSBBoxClusterStrategy.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSBBoxClusterStrategy.shtml
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSFixedClusterStrategy.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSFixedClusterStrategy.shtml
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSFeatures.php /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSFeatures.html
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSOpenLayers.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSOpenLayers.shtml
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSOpenLayers2.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSOpenLayers2.shtml
    redirect 301 /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSOpenSpace.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSOpenSpace.shtml
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Music/AtlanticRollers/AtlanticRollers.html /Macfarlane/Music/AtlanticRollers.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Music/AtlanticRollers/AtlanticRollers.gif /Macfarlane/Music/AtlanticRollers.gif
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Music/BringUsInGoodAle/BringUsInGoodAle.html /Macfarlane/Music/BringUsInGoodAle.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Music/CheddarGorge/CheddarGorge.html /Macfarlane/Music/CheddarGorge.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Music/DaysEnd/DaysEnd.html /Macfarlane/Music/DaysEnd.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Music/MadMarchGales/MadMarchGales.html /Macfarlane/Music/MadMarchGales.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Music/MartinSaidToHisMan/MartinSaidToHisMan.html /Macfarlane/Music/MartinSaidToHisMan.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Music/MingulayBoatSong/MingulayBoatSong.html /Macfarlane/Music/MingulayBoatSong.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Music/MingulayBoatSong/MingulayBoatSong.gif /Macfarlane/Music/MingulayBoatSong.gif
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Music/PerfumeOnMyMind/PerfumeOnMyMind.html /Macfarlane/Music/PerfumeOnMyMind.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Music/PoorOldHeap/PoorOldHeap.html /Macfarlane/Music/PoorOldHeap.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Music/SallyInTheWoods/SallyInTheWoods.html /Macfarlane/Music/SallyInTheWoods.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Music/SallyInTheWoods/SallyInTheWoods.gif /Macfarlane/Music/SallyInTheWoods.gif
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Music/SallyInTheWoods/SallyInTheWoods.mid /Macfarlane/Music/SallyInTheWoods.mid
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Music/SallyInTheWoods/SallyInTheWoods.mp3 /Macfarlane/Music/SallyInTheWoods.mp3
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/MusicTheory/Roman/Roman.html /Macfarlane/MusicTheory/Roman.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/Blackout/Blackout.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/Blackout.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/Cavemen/Cavemen.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/Cavemen.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/Edwina/Edwina.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/Edwina.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/EyesOfSuchBlue/EyesOfSuchBlue.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/EyesOfSuchBlue.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/Fireside/Fireside.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/Fireside.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/FirstAndLast/FirstAndLast.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/FirstAndLast.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/Fox/Fox.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/Fox.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/J/J.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/J.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/Moonlight/Moonlight.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/Moonlight.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/NightRainOnBlackheath/NightRainOnBlackheath.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/NightRainOnBlackheath.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/Posers/Posers.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/Posers.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/RunawayTrain/RunawayTrain.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/RunawayTrain.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/Scotland/Scotland.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/Scotland.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/SmittenAgain/SmittenAgain.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/SmittenAgain.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/SunriseOverLondon/SunriseOverLondon.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/SunriseOverLondon.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/YearInEssex/YearInEssex.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/CharlesMacfarlane/YearInEssex.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/CapeHorn/CapeHorn.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/GilesDixey/CapeHorn.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/CrossingTheBar/CrossingTheBar.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/AlfredTennyson/CrossingTheBar.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/Eagle/Eagle.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/AlfredTennyson/Eagle.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/Ulysses/Ulysses.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/AlfredTennyson/Ulysses.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/SayNotTheStruggle/SayNotTheStruggle.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/ArthurHughClough/SayNotTheStruggle.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/RollingEnglishRoad/RollingEnglishRoad.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/GilbertKeithChesterton/RollingEnglishRoad.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/OldShips/OldShips.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/JamesElroyFlecker/OldShips.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/EpitaphForCharlesII/EpitaphForCharlesII.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/JohnWilmot/EpitaphForCharlesII.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/DoverBeach/DoverBeach.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/MatthewArnold/DoverBeach.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/HomeThoughtsFromAbroad/HomeThoughtsFromAbroad.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/RobertBrowning/HomeThoughtsFromAbroad.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/AreYouDiggingOnMyGrave/AreYouDiggingOnMyGrave.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/ThomasHardy/AreYouDiggingOnMyGrave.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/BrokenAppointment/BrokenAppointment.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/ThomasHardy/BrokenAppointment.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/IFoundHerOutThere/IFoundHerOutThere.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/ThomasHardy/IFoundHerOutThere.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/NeutralTones/NeutralTones.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/ThomasHardy/NeutralTones.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Poetry/AnthemForDoomedYouth/AnthemForDoomedYouth.html /Macfarlane/Poetry/WilfredOwen/AnthemForDoomedYouth.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/Accents/Accents.html /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/Accents.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/DudLust/DudLust.html /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/DudLust.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/HerefordshireHertfordshire/HerefordshireHertfordshire.html /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/HerefordshireHertfordshire.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/Livermudlian/Livermudlian.html /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/Livermudlian.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/PassAssHole/PassAssHole.html /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/PassAssHole.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/PumpUpTheVolume/PumpUpTheVolume.html /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/PumpUpTheVolume.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/SundayPMStroll/SundayPMStroll.html /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/SundayPMStroll.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/VicarDogCatDuck/VicarDogCatDuck.html /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/VicarDogCatDuck.html
    redirect 301 /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/WatermansArms/WatermansArms.html /Macfarlane/Reminiscences/WatermansArms.html
    redirect 301 /Shinness/ShinnessBroadband20161130.html /Shinness/FTTCPlans.html
    redirect 301 /PrivTest/DTM-Asc2SRTM.js /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/OSvsSRTM.html
    redirect 301 /PrivTest/DTM-Asc2SRTM.js.txt /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/OSvsSRTM.html
    redirect 301 /PrivTest/DTM-Asc2SRTM.py /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/OSvsSRTM.html
    redirect 301 /PrivTest/DTM-Asc2SRTM.py.txt /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/OSvsSRTM.html
    redirect 301 /PrivTest/DTM-Asc2SRTM.png /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/OSvsSRTM.html
    redirect 301 /PrivTest/T502SRTM.png /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/OSvsSRTM.html
    redirect 301 /PrivTest/JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/TerrestrialTV/TerrestrialCalculator.html /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/TerrestrialTV/TerrestrialCalculator.shtml
    redirect 301 /PrivTest/JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/TerrestrialTV/TerrestrialCalculator.php /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/TerrestrialTV/TerrestrialCalculator.shtml
    redirect 301 /Test/SatelliteCalculator.html /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/SatelliteTV/SatelliteCalculator.shtml
    redirect 301 /Test/SatelliteGeneral.html /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/SatelliteTV/SatelliteGeneral.html
    redirect 301 /Test/SatellitePerspective.html /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/SatelliteTV/SatellitePerspective.html
    redirect 301 /Test/SatellitePerspective1.jpg /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/SatelliteTV/SatellitePerspective1.jpg
    redirect 301 /Test/UKTerrestrialTVTest.html /JavaJive/AudioVisualTV/TerrestrialTV/TerrestrialCalculator.shtml
    redirect 301 /Test/Forms.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/Forms.html
    redirect 301 /Test/Google_with_Google.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/GoogleGoogle.shtml
    redirect 301 /Test/Google_with_OpenLayers.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/GoogleOpenLayers.shtml
    redirect 301 /Test/UKOrdnance_Survey_with_OpenLayers.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSOpenLayers.shtml
    redirect 301 /Test/UKOrdnance_Survey_with_OpenSpace.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSOpenSpace.shtml
    redirect 301 /Test/UKOSBBoxClusterStrategy.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSBBoxClusterStrategy.shtml
    redirect 301 /Test/UKOSFixedClusterStrategy.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSFixedClusterStrategy.shtml
    redirect 301 /Test/UKOSOpenSpace.html /JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSOpenSpace.shtml
    redirect 301 /Test/GoogleOLControls.html /Test/GoogleOLControls.shtml
    redirect 301 /Test/GoogleOLScales.html /Test/GoogleOLScales.shtml
    redirect 301 /Test/GoogleScales.png /Test/GoogleOLScales.shtml
    redirect 301 /Test/GMLIEBug_Metacarta.html /Test/DeadMapDemo.html
    redirect 301 /Test/GMLIEBug_UKOS.html /Test/DeadMapDemo.html
    redirect 301 /Test/Google-GoogleAPI.png /Test/DeadMapDemo.html
    redirect 301 /Test/Google-OpenLayers.png /Test/DeadMapDemo.html
    redirect 301 /Test/GoogleInfoWindow.html /Test/DeadMapDemo.html
    redirect 301 /Test/GoogleMouseTest.html /Test/DeadMapDemo.html
    redirect 301 /Test/GoogleOpenLayersBugs.html /Test/DeadMapDemo.html
    redirect 301 /Test/LayerBugTest.html /Test/DeadMapDemo.html
    redirect 301 /Test/UKOrdnance_Survey_with_OpenLayers%20-%20Marker%20Bug.html /Test/DeadMapDemo.html
    redirect 301 "/Test/UKOrdnance_Survey_with_OpenLayers - Marker Bug.html" /Test/DeadMapDemo.html
```

Comment: We would need to see your `.htaccess` file. If some redirects work and others don't then it suggests a conflict. You are using mod_alias `Redirect`, but if your `.htaccess` is "quite complex" then you are probably using mod_rewrite as well? This could result in a conflict. You also appear to have directories of the same name as file basenames (`/HardwareFaults` and `HardwareFaults.html`) - if `MultiViews` is enabled then this can also result in a conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the help ... I'll add the .htaccess file shortly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, when some redirects work and others don't then it suggests a conflict of some kind. The first thing to try (since it's quick) is to disable `MultiViews` (it's disabled by default on Apache, but it often gets enabled in many shared server environments):

```
Options -Indexes +Includes -MultiViews
```

Without knowing your filesystem structure, it's not clear whether this will have any benefit or not. But if you have directories and file basenames that share the same name then `MultiViews` (part of mod_negotiation) can cause problems. For instance, a request for `/PCHardware/HardwareFaults` could result in the file `HardwareFaults.html` being served, rather than the directory index inside the physical directory `/HardwareFaults` (if that was how your filesystem was structured).

Comment: Thanks so much for this clear answer that has completely fixed the problem